# Role of invertibility in creating a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inverse

[image]

Can someone please explain the logic behind this solution simply?

I don't understand how the statements are equivalent (must be some formula I've never seen before), or how the invertibility proves a basis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Q = (t_1, \dots, t_n)
$$
we have
$$
[t_i]_T = e_i = A t_i
$$
where the $e_i$ are the canonical base vectors. So we need a matrix $A$ with
$$
A Q = I \iff \\
A = Q^{-1}
$$
That is why
$$
[u]_T = Q^{-1} u
$$
The $n$ vectors $Q^{-1} v_i$ form a basis if they are linear independent, thus if the system
$$
Q^{-1}V x = (Q^{-1} v_1, \dotsc, Q^{-1} v_n) x = 0
$$
has the only solution vector $x = 0$. This is the case because
$$
\det(Q^{-1} V) = \det(Q^{-1}) \det(V) \ne 0
$$
because $Q$ is invertible and $V$ is a matrix of basis vectors.

Comment: Why must AQ = I? I don't really understand how it's necessary to have the identity matrix be involved here

Comment: A basis vector $b_i$ regarding its own basis always has the coordinates of the canonical vector $e_i$, and $I = (e_1, \dotsc, e_n)$.

Comment: What exactly is a canonical vector? Is it like the corresponding rref column? Your edited answer makes perfect sense though

Comment: $e_i$ has the $i$-th component $1$ and all other components $0$.